# What books, articles, blog posts about XNA performance?

Tags: c#, performance, xna

Do you know some books, articles, blogs about how to write code to keep good performance in XNA?
I know that there are principles in XNA, strict rules what to do and what to avoid, what solutions are better.

Comment: I believe this question is too broad to answer.

Comment: I think it is strict, I need a book, article or blog when i can learn how to write code in XNA. I don't understand what's unclear here?

Comment: Its not asking for a specific details. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I saw a dozens of questions about books, articles, learning. Let the community decide if they interested in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Create from MSDN](http://create.msdn.com) - lots of examples, tutorials and articles here.

[Riemers](http://www.riemers.net/) - XNA Tutorials here.

[Shawn Hargreaves blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/).

[Programming Guide for HLSL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509635%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

[XNA 3.1 to 4 Cheatsheet](http://www.nelxon.com/blog/xna-3-1-to-xna-4-0-cheatsheet/).

[XNA Meeting Point](http://xnameetingpoint.web.officelive.com/EnglishArchiveXNA4.aspx) - lots of shader tutorials here.

[The Danger Zone](http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/samples-tutorials-tools/depth-of-field-sample/) - Great tutorials/articles here.

[Sgt Conker](http://www.sgtconker.com/) - again, more tutorials/articles here.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of resources that I use on a regular basis.

This is Shawn Hargreave's blog.  Chock full of useful bits.  He is one of the XNA masterminds, so he know what he is talking about.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/

Of course MSDN is always a good choice.  They will get you the basics, and mode advanced stuff if you feel like digging deep enough.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb200104.aspx

Also, the DirectX SDK has a bunch of good profiling tools, like PIX so you can do tuning and what not, and learn a few tricks for yourself.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to mention that XNA Meeting Point is moving to a new host.

The new address is: http://xnameetingpoint.weebly.com , and the English tutorials are available at http://xnameetingpoint.weebly.com/xna-tutorials.html

Note that some of the content is being added.

I'll post here when the transition is over and we added all our content online.